# Как найти первый символ массива?

Tags: javascript

Как найти первый символ  массива?

Нужно проверять стоит ли # у хештега

Comment: Шта? Индекс цифровой и порядковый.

Answer (score 1):

Первый символ строки можно получить так:

```
array[0]
```

Проверка '#' в начале строки:

```
if(array[0] == '#'){
    //Ваш код
}
```